# Does multi-column BRIN column order matter?

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I have a large amount of data (500+ mil rows) in a table that I need to filter/query in real-time. I haven't been able to get satisfactory performance OR predictable query plans using regular b-tree indexes. I thought that using a BRIN would help a lot, but because our data cannot be inserted in any controlled physical ordering that I need to query by, I have set up a `MATERIALIZED VIEW` to select the data (including joined data) and sort it in a specific order. Something along the lines of...

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW my_view AS
    SELECT a.one, b.two, b.three, c.four, c.five, c.six
    FROM a, b, c WHERE ...joins
    ORDER BY b.three, b.two, a.one, c.four;
```

I then created the index based on multiple columns, since **all** specified columns will **always** be used in the single query this view is meant for.

```
CREATE INDEX my_view_idx ON my_view
    USING BRIN (three, two, one, four) WITH (pages_per_range = 64);
```

I ordered the columns (both in the table *and* in the BRIN) based on selectivity, meaning `b.three` will filter out 80% of the records (ie. only 20% of records will match), `b.two` will filter out 70%, etc.

**Was ordering the BRIN columns the same as the physical sorting of the table necessary?** I cannot find any resources that describe this. The *closest* thing I could find was from: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/indexes-multicolumn.html ...

> A multicolumn BRIN index can be used with query conditions that involve any subset of the index's columns. Like GIN and unlike B-tree or GiST, index search effectiveness is the same regardless of which index column(s) the query conditions use.

... but that doesn't describe column *ordering*, only *inclusion in a query*.

I could experiment (and have been, with surprisingly good results), but it's a slow process as it takes 2+ hours to materialize the view and build the index, so I would love to have some sort of factual basis for my guessing to avoid wasting lots of time.

Comment: same question here...have you ever tried to use different columns order and compare their performance?

Comment: Unfortunately, my tests were very limited just because of how long it took to materialize the view. We've since refactored and are no longer using this approach, so I'm really unsure about performance differences still :(

Answer (score 1):

I think the order of columns in BRIN index doesn't matter - according to the same doc: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/indexes-multicolumn.html

> Like GIN and unlike B-tree or GiST, index search effectiveness is the same regardless of which index column(s) the query conditions use.

Looks like the order is only important for B-tree and GiST.

Comment: That's exactly the part that the OP quoted, and said "*but that doesn't describe column ordering, only inclusion in a query*".